# Criar um data frame separando termos de uma string em colunas

Tags: r

Como faço para criar um `data.frame` separando cada termo ligado por `_` em colunas

```
"WZ_311205_20131007_20131008113131_RUA_RAMAL_FARIA_TEMP_DATA_ _AVENIDA_DADOS_PORTO_9.xml"
"WZ_311205_20131007_20131008113131_RUA_RAMAL_FARIA_TEMP_DATA_ _AVENIDA_DADOS_PORTO_10.xml"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso, tu pode utilizar a função `stringr::str_split_fixed`:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("WZ_311205_20131007_20131008113131_RUA_RAMAL_FARIA_TEMP_DATA_ _AVENIDA_DADOS_PORTO_9.xml", 
"WZ_311205_20131007_20131008113131_RUA_RAMAL_FARIA_TEMP_DATA_ _AVENIDA_DADOS_PORTO_10.xml"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)) # Leitura da base de dados

ncols <- max(apply(df, 1, function(x) str_count(x, "_")))+1 # Número de colunas a serem criadas + 1

stringr::str_split_fixed(df$V1, "_", n=ncols)
```